# Redirect question mark URL to the original URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect the following URL

```
https://www.example.com/vmi10/? to https://www.example.com/vmi10/
```

This is a WordPress site. How can I do that? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Kindly do share your htaccess file in your question if you have any, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule as your **topmost** rule in main .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?\s
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,NE,R=301]

# other WP rules below this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove empty query string from the url we use ^$ in our `RewriteCond` Condition Pattern like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `https://www.example.com/vmi10/? to https://www.example.com/vmi10/`

This won't affect any url with non empty query string.

Test it here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=34570386-6b48-486b-ba84-32a222921502

Comment: This will cause infinite redirects